# ModalPopupExtender disappers after dropdownlist's selected index change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, drop-down-menu, modalpopupextender

I want to get some value from dropdown's selected index change and bind them to textox or other control but problem is that popup disappear after selected index changed. Need Solution.
code is

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <div>
        <div>
               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="Button1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" 
                Drag="True" DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" 
                OkControlID="btncancel" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Button1">
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        first name<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        country <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>india</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>pakistan</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>usa</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>england</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="select"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        selected country<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Submit" />
        <input id="btncancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

And code behind is

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox9.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you just need to re-issue the show method:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox9.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    Button1_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
}
```

Comment: what if my ModalPopUpExtender is in a custom user control and I dont have access to the ModalPopUpExtender from the user control?

Comment: @Rafael - You would need to make it a public property from your custom user control. That way you'd be able to access it from your page.